# Flutter - Error implementing interface with Freezed

Tags: flutter, freezed

I'm trying to programme to an interface with [Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#mixins-and-interfaces-for-individual-classes-for-union-types). I want to be able to specify all over my app, the type `IUserRegistrationEntity`;

My interface:

```
abstract class IUserRegistrationEntity {
  String nickName;
  String email;
  String confirmEmail;
  String password;
  String confirmPassword;
}
```

My freezed class:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:vepo/domain/user_registration/i_user_registration_entity.dart';

part 'user_registration_entity.freezed.dart';

@freezed
abstract class UserRegistrationEntity with _$UserRegistrationEntity {
  @Implements(IUserRegistrationEntity)
  factory UserRegistrationEntity(
      {String nickName,
      String email,
      String confirmEmail,
      String password,
      String confirmPassword}) = _UserRegistrationEntity;
}
```

Getting the error when running the app:

```
lib/domain/user_registration/user_registration_entity.freezed.dart:165:7: Error: The non-abstract class '_$_UserRegistrationEntity' is missing implementations for these members:
 - IUserRegistrationEntity.confirmEmail
 - IUserRegistrationEntity.confirmPassword
 - IUserRegistrationEntity.email
 - IUserRegistrationEntity.nickName
 - IUserRegistrationEntity.password
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class _$_UserRegistrationEntity implements _UserRegistrationEntity {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/domain/user_registration/i_user_registration_entity.dart:4:10: Context: 'IUserRegistrationEntity.confirmEmail' is defined here.
  String confirmEmail;

         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/domain/user_registration/i_user_registration_entity.dart:6:10: Context: 'IUserRegistrationEntity.confirmPassword' is defined here.
  String confirmPassword;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/domain/user_registration/i_user_registration_entity.dart:3:10: Context: 'IUserRegistrationEntity.email' is defined here.
  String email;
         ^^^^^
lib/domain/user_registration/i_user_registration_entity.dart:2:10: Context: 'IUserRegistrationEntity.nickName' is defined here.
  String nickName;
         ^^^^^^^^

lib/domain/user_registration/i_user_registration_entity.dart:5:10: Context: 'IUserRegistrationEntity.password' is defined here.
  String password;

         ^^^^^^^^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Does this quote from the package docs mean it is not possible?.

> Note 2: You cannot use @With/@Implements with freezed classes. Freezed
> classes can neither be extended nor implemented.

Keen to know if people think this is a drawback if so.

Comment: Shouldn't there be `const` before the `factory` constructor for generated factories?

Comment: @rkdupr0n Yes I think so thanks, however still getting the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested out your code and found the problem from the generated file. Thing is, freezed doesn't override setters from the implemented abstract class. So, for your `IUserRegistrationEntity`, make the parameters as getters. Like so:

```
abstract class IUserRegistrationEntity {
  String get nickName;
  String get email;
  String get confirmEmail;
  String get password;
  String get confirmPassword;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I don't suppose you know how to make `IUserRegistrationEntity` know about the freezed functions such as `copyWith`? As my interface is not useful without that. I may need to ask another question.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest making another freezed class keeping `IUserRegistrationEntity` as base. Wait, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't make `IUserRegistrationEntity` know about freezed functions. However, you can do what I commented before and use that class. However, the new class would be exactly like `UserRegistrationEntity`.

Comment: Thank you. I used your solution. I have just built upon it to solve the second problem that I asked you about, so I posted it in another answer in case anyone else is interested in doing something similar.

Answer (score 3):

I used rkdupr0n's solution. I would just like to say that I also made the `IUserRegistrationEntity` interface know about the Freezed package's functions so that I could call them when programming to the `IUserRegistrationEntity` interface. Well, just the ones that I need currently. I will add the rest soon.

Freezed class becomes:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:vepo/domain/user_registration/i_user_registration_entity.dart';

part 'user_registration_entity.freezed.dart';
part 'user_registration_entity.g.dart';

@freezed
abstract class UserRegistrationEntity with _$UserRegistrationEntity {
  @Implements.fromString(
      'IUserRegistrationEntity<\$UserRegistrationEntityCopyWith<IUserRegistrationEntity>>')
  const factory UserRegistrationEntity(
      {String nickName,
      String email,
      String confirmEmail,
      String password,
      String confirmPassword}) = _IUserRegistrationEntity;

  factory UserRegistrationEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserRegistrationEntityFromJson(json);
}
```

Interface:

```
abstract class IUserRegistrationEntity<T> extends FreezedClass<T> {
  String get nickName;
  String get email;
  String get confirmEmail;
  String get password;
  String get confirmPassword;
}

abstract class FreezedClass<T> {
  T get copyWith;
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add private empty constructer code

example if you are are generating a freezed user class

```
@freezed
abstract class User with _$User {
  const User._(); // add this
}
```

it would look like that