# how to extend `Freezed` abstact classes

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed

update: edited as my original question is answered in this [issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/327),

given an freezed class cannot directly implement other classes (see issue above)

`Foo.baz` can implement `Baz` as below

```dart
abstract class Baz<T> {
  const Baz(this.data);
  final T data;
}
```

```dart
@freezed
abstract class Foo<T> with _$Foo<T> {
  @Implements(Baz)
  const factory Foo.baz(T data) = _FooBaz;
}
```

but the `Type T` doesn't get passed to the implemented `Baz` in the

```dart
abstract class _FooBaz<T> implements Foo<T>, Baz<dynamic> { /// `<= HERE!!!!`
  const factory _FooBaz(T data) = _$_FooBaz<T>;

  T get data;
  _$FooBazCopyWith<T, _FooBaz<T>> get copyWith;
}
```

if I try to pass the the `Type` inside `@Implements`
I get the error

`Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions. Try making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor.`

[image: screenshot]

is there any way to correctly pass the type to the implemented class?

Comment: Another interesting question is how could I test a sealed union created with Freezed?

Comment: U can try something like this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65264172/11566145